# Qt - QtDomElement comparison, XML object comparison

Tags: c++, xml, qt, compare, arrays

I am to compare XML files, which are available as QtDomElement objects. There is no Qt method to do so IMO.

1. what is most efficient way to compare XML files, using Qt ? What are alternative solutions ?
2. what if I more precisely want to compare QDomElement objects ?
3. is it a good idea to first convert QDomElement to QByteArray, and then compare QByteArray (and how to ?)
4. when converting a QDomDocument to Qbytearrays, is the order of XML headers the same if same header and contents are present in both files in different order ?

for instance, if i have

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

and

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

i would the compare to return true. When i convert to QByteArray, would order be the same in both QByteArray ? How to compare the QByteArrays, as to return true in this case for a comparison ?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20832